# How can I create an alias for Finder in OS X El Capitan?

Tags: finder, macos, launchpad, alias

I want to add a Finder shortcut to my Launchpad, but I am unable to do it.

Is there any way to create an alias for Finder in OS X El Capitan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the following command in Terminal (it will create a symbolic link for all users):

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app /Applications
```

Or just for currently logged on user:

```
ln -s /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app ~/Applications
```

Finder will appear in the applications list opened with Launchpad.